# Is there any version of Sobolev embedding with respect to $W^{k,p}_0$, or for unbounded domain $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, soft-question, sobolev-spaces

The ordinary Sobolev embedding states that, if $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$ is a bounded Lipschitz domain, then for $kp>n$ we have an embedding $W^{k,p}(\Omega) \subset C^0(\Omega)$; while for $kp<n$ we have $W^{k,p}(\Omega) \subset L^q(\Omega)$ for $q< \frac{np}{n-kp}$.

> **Question:** Is there any version of the Sobolev embedding theorem which is with respect to $W^{k,p}_0(\Omega)$ instead of $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$? What if we assume $\Omega$ is unbounded?
>
> For my interest, is there a version that states $W^{1,p}(\mathbb R) \subset C^0(\mathbb R)$?

*Notation:* Denote by $C^\infty_0$ the set of all real-valued smooth functions $f$ on
$\mathbb R$ such that $\lim_{x\to \pm\infty} f(x)=0$. Let $W^{1,p}_0$ be the completion of $C^\infty_0$ with respect to the Sobolev norm $||\cdot||_{W^{1,p}}$

Comment: For the case $k = 1$ you can refer to Chapter 9 of the book of Brezis (Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and PDEs). In particular you should see Corollary 9.14 and Theorem 9.16 for the case with $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ with $\Omega$ bounded, open and regular, Remark 14 for the case where $\Omega$ is not bounded and Remark 20 for the case with $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ (in the latter you don't need $\Omega$ to be regular but just bounded and open).

Comment: Thanks. How about $W^{1,p}(\mathbb R) \subset C^0 (\mathbb R)$? Is this true?

Comment: For $p>N$, $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^N) \subset L^\infty (\mathbb{R}^N)$ with continuous injection. And every function in $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ with $p>N$ admits a continuous representative.

Comment: Any reference do you know?

Comment: In the book by Haim Brezis, "Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations" (Chapter 9), there is written exactly what I wrote here. I didn't read it but I think also the book "Sobolev Spaces" by Adams and Fournier can be very useful. Surely there is something also on "Partial Differential Equations" by Lawrence Evans.

Answer (score 3):

For $W_0^{k,p}(\Omega)$ with $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ open, yes. The idea is to establish the relevant inequalities for $u \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ (which is dense in $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ as you define it by mollification) and extend by density, which is probably what you learnt in the ordinary version of the theorem minus the extra step of extending it via extension operators.

This is done for example in Evans' PDE book, where he proves the Gagliardo-Nirenburg-Sobolev inequality and Morrey's inequality in $C_c^1(\mathbb R^n).$ The same proof however, can also be used to establish the result in $C_c^1(\Omega)$ for $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ open.